# R code for logit generates values greater than 1?

Tags: r

The logistic transformation is supposed to generate values in (0,1). But if you look at the following logistic transformation, you will see that it creates values greater than 1. Where I am going wrong?

```
lambda1=0
out=matrix(NA,400,1)
for (i in 1:400){
  lambda1[i+1]=((exp(0.8*lambda1[i]+rnorm(1)))/(1+exp(0.8*lambda1[i]+rnorm(1))))
  out[i]=lambda1[i]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Each time you call `rnorm(1)` you are getting a different random draw, so the random value in the numerator and denominator may be different.

Note that `exp(x) / (1+exp(x))` is equivalent to `1 / (1 + exp(-x))`, so you could instead do:

```
lambda1=0
out=matrix(NA,400,1)
for (i in 1:400){
  lambda1[i+1]=(1/(1+exp(-(0.8*lambda1[i]+rnorm(1)))))
  out[i]=lambda1[i]
}
summary(lambda1)
#    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#  0.0000  0.4523  0.6352  0.6119  0.7719  0.9682
```

Note: for very large vectors, you will probably find it more efficient to preallocate `lambda1` and to compute `out` at the end in one shot (I'll assume you actually want elements 2 through 401 in `out` instead of elements 1 through 400):

```
lambda1 <- rep(0, 401)
for (i in 1:400) lambda1[i+1]=(1/(1+exp(-(0.8*lambda1[i]+rnorm(1)))))
out <- matrix(tail(lambda1, -1))
```

Comment: "the random value in the numerator and denominator may be different" in fact, the probability of them being equal is _zero_ because the normal distribution is continuous. fun fact

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely clear on exactly what you want to accomplish here.  But the reason you are getting values outside the interval [0,1] is that you have two calls to `rnorm()`, which give you two different values.

You can remedy this (and I think get (close to) what you want) by replacing

```
lambda1[i+1]=((exp(0.8*lambda1[i]+rnorm(1)))/(1+exp(0.8*lambda1[i]+rnorm(1))))
```

with

```
r = exp(0.8*lambda1[i] + rnorm(1))
lambda1[i+1] = r/(1+r)
```